# btrfs and missing free space

Tags: filesystem, disk-usage, btrfs, compression

I converted my ext4 partition to btrfs and deleted the save subvolume after doing so. Then I enabled the compression (lzo) of the filessystem in the fstab file and everything is correct so far.

Then I forced the compression of all files using the defragmentation command with the parameter -c that the new compression is applied to all files.

While doing so, I noticed that my ssd got completly filled up - before I had 6gigs of free space. No I got nothing left.

```
easteregg@x201s:~$ btrfs fi df /
Data: total=50.00GB, used=49.17GB
System: total=32.00MB, used=4.00KB
Metadata: total=24.50GB, used=9.86GB
```

and

```
easteregg@x201s:~$ df -ha
Filesystem        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1          75G   60G  852M  99% /
```

So now. How can I regain my free space. I expected to gain more space because of the lzo compression. And now!

The fs is correctly mounted.

```
easteregg@x201s:~$ mount
/dev/sda1 on / type btrfs (rw,noatime,ssd,compress=lzo)
```

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Comment: I now have got the point: you can't do online re-balancing. That explains why nothing worked for me. So I just booted up my rescue system and just did a re-balance of the whole disk and afterwards I carried out the defragmentation command with compression enabled. Now I have got about 17 gigs of free space! nice :)

Comment: As a best practice, only keep a minimal set of snapshots and remove unnecessary ones to avoid wasting of space on the volume, because btrfs is copy-on-write file system, as time goes on, more and more data blocks will be changed, thus making snapshots occupying more and more space on the disk.

Comment: See also [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/464074), which has a thorough explanation and useful comments.

Answer (score 10):

I know this question is old - but as of today the balance command solves this stuff:

During conversion a lot of space will be allcoated to move stuff to it. Once it is allocated, it will not show up as "free" or "unallocated" anymore. To fix this simply start a balance

```
btrfs balance start "path"
```

you can also tell the balance command, to only balance chunks, which are used for acertain percentage - like 0% which would mean the chunks are empty:

```
btrfs balance start "path" -dusage=0 -musage=0
```

parameter -d means options for the data.
parameter -m means options for the metadata.

play with the balance command, it should help.

Comment: For an old response, to an even older question, this saved me today.  Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Look at the output from `btrfs fi df`:

```
Data: total=50.00GB, used=49.17GB
System: total=32.00MB, used=4.00KB
Metadata: total=24.50GB, used=9.86GB
```

The `total` part is the allocated space, while `used` is the actually used by btrfs. **The difference between `total` and `used` (around 15 GB) is your missing space.** As you can see, it has already been allocated for metadata blocks.

I only have hobby experience with btrfs, but I don't think a ext4 conversion is the best way to create a well laid out btrfs filesystem. Fortunately, you can rebalance the whole filesystem to make it re-do all allocations.

As always, use backups.