# Btrfs: It is safe to delete @home subvolume in this case?

Tags: btrfs

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 server with btrfs (SSD drive) as /, and I have a bind of another drive (SATA) to /home. The SSD drive has reported that is out of free space, so [I read this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464074/ubuntu-thinks-btrfs-disk-is-full-but-its-not), applied some of the suggestions, and removed some files. This is what btrfs now reports:

```
# btrfs fi show /
Label: system  uuid: 2322b989-2110-494b-96b0-40aaee2f3998
    Total devices 1 FS bytes used 6.20GiB
    devid    1 size 26.08GiB used 22.52GiB path /dev/sdc1

# btrfs fi df /
Data, single: total=21.76GiB, used=5.69GiB
System, single: total=4.00MiB, used=16.00KiB
Metadata, single: total=776.00MiB, used=522.03MiB

# btrfs subvolume list /

ID 257 gen 2090434 top level 5 path @
ID 258 gen 1048023 top level 5 path @home

df -h
/dev/sdc1        27G  6.3G   20G  25% /
```

It is safe to remove @home as it is actually a bind to another drive?
But before that, I just want to be sure I'm reading the above numbers correctly... The drive is using around 6GB out of 26G, right?

**UPDATE**

This is my fstab (relevant parts):

```
UUID=2322b989-2110-494b-96b0-40aaee2f3998   /   btrfs   noatime,nodiratime,notreelog,ssd,discard,subvol=@   0   1

UUID=858a4a9d-a901-47c7-89d2-0ef97ef6f23f   /mnt/ext ext4  defaults,acl,user_xattr,noatime,nodiratime 0  1

/mnt/ext/home /home   none bind
```

Comment: It depends on how do you mount your drives in `fstab`.

Comment: @Pilot6: added fstab part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can safely remove the `@home` subvolume. It is not mounted anywhere on boot.

I recommend to check if there is anything important there left. You can unmount the HDD for that and see what is in `/home`.

Comment: Thanks Pilot6, I will do that this weekend (as the server is running through the week). The correct way to remove it would be: `btrfs subvolume delete /@home`, right? One more thing: is my assumption that the drive is using around 6GB correct?

Comment: Yes, all is corect.